# Unable to filter Elements of Foreign Key Model using Django-Rest

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

> models.py

```
class ViewType(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=128, db_column='view_name')
    viewType = models.CharField(max_length=64, choices=VIEW_TYPES, db_column='view_type')
    bannerImage = models.CharField(max_length=1024, db_column='banner_image', blank=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=16, db_column='status', choices=ITEM_STATUS, default = 'active')
    position = models.IntegerField(db_column='position', default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['position']

# List Item
class List(models.Model):
    position = models.IntegerField(db_column='postion', default=0)
    associatedView = models.ForeignKey(ViewType, db_column='associated_view', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, related_name='list')
    bannerImage = models.CharField(max_length=1024, db_column='banner_image', blank=True)
    listingPrice = models.CharField(max_length=32, db_column='listing_price', blank=True)
    listingCurrency = models.CharField(max_length=32, db_column='listing_currency', blank=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=16, db_column='status', choices=ITEM_STATUS, default = 'preview')
    expireAt = models.DateTimeField(null=False, blank=False, db_column='expire_at')
    createdAt = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True, blank=True, db_column='created_at')
    updatedAt = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, null=True, blank=True, db_column='updated_at')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.position

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'List Items'
        verbose_name_plural = 'List Items'

class ViewAll(models.Model):
    isEnabled = models.BooleanField(db_column='is_enabled')
    associatedView =  models.OneToOneField(ViewType, db_column='associated_view', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, related_name='viewAll')
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'View Widget'
        verbose_name_plural = 'View All Widgets'
```

> serializer.py

```
class ViewAllSerializer (serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ViewAll
        fields = '__all__'

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        data = super(ViewAllSerializer, self).to_representation(instance)
        data['redirection'] = RedirectionSerializer(instance.redirection).data
        return data

class ListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = List
        fields = '__all__'
    def to_representation(self, instance):
        data = super(ListSerializer, self).to_representation(instance)
        data['redirection'] = RedirectionSerializer(instance.redirection).data
        return data        

class ViewTypeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    list = ListSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    viewAll = ViewAllSerializer(read_only=True, many=False)
    class Meta:
        model = ViewType
        fields = '__all__'
```

> views.py

```
class ViewAllViewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = ViewAll.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ViewAllSerializer
    http_method_names = ['get']

class ListViewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = List.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ListSerializer
    http_method_names = ['get']

class ViewTypeViewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = ViewType.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ViewTypeSerializer
    http_method_names = ['get']

    # http://example.com/api/purchases?username=denvercoder9
    def get_queryset(self):
            queryset = ViewType.objects.all()
            status = self.request.query_params.get('status', None)
            print (status)
            if status:
                queryset = queryset.filter(status=status, list__status=status, list__expireAt__gt=datetime.datetime.now())
                #print(queryset)
                #print([i.list.expireAt for i in queryset])
            return queryset
```

I want to filter the results of the above query such that ViewType.status and List.status can both be filtered. Also, need to show only elements that have a future Expiry Date. 
Currently, I can only filter ViewType.status . I hit the following url

http://localhost:8001/mobilehome/api/mobile_home_router/?status=active
and I above filter is unable to fetch the values in list__status and list__expireAt or it 
results. 
The result set returned is also weird, since I get multiple ViewType of the same id.

> [{id=1, list[4 elements], viewAll{}},{id=1, list[4 elements],
>   viewAll{}},{id=1, list[4 elements], viewAll{}},{id=1, list[4
>   elements], viewAll{}}, {id=2, list[6 elements], viewAll{}}, {id=2,
>   list[6 elements], viewAll{}},{id=2, list[6 elements],
>   viewAll{}},{id=2, list[6 elements], viewAll{}},{id=2, list[6
>   elements], viewAll{}},{id=2, list[6 elements], viewAll{}}]

while the result I need is

> [{id=1, list[4 elements], viewAll{}}, [{id=2, list[6 elements],
>   viewAll{}}]

Comment: `list__expireAt_gt > datetime.datetime.now()` should be `list__expireAt__gt=datetime.datetime.now()`

Comment: it still returns the same result [{id=1, list[4 elements], viewAll{}},{id=1, list[4 elements], viewAll{}},{id=1, list[4 elements], viewAll{}},{id=1, list[4 elements], viewAll{}}, {id=2, list[6 elements], viewAll{}}, {id=2, list[6 elements], viewAll{}},{id=2, list[6 elements], viewAll{}},{id=2, list[6 elements], viewAll{}},{id=2, list[6 elements], viewAll{}},{id=2, list[6 elements], viewAll{}}] while the result I need is 
[{id=1, list[4 elements], viewAll{}}, [{id=2, list[6 elements], viewAll{}}]

Comment: try to add `.distinct()` to your query.

Comment: @SergeyPugach this does reduce the count, but the filters are still not working in the ForeignKey namely list__status=status and list__expireAt__gt = =datetime.datetime.now()

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem can you assist with this? queryset = queryset.filter(status=status, list__status=status, list__expireAt__gt=datetime.datetime.now()) , list__status and list__expireAt__gt donot work.